# Auto Smartports macros

Tags: switch

I am not an expert at networking, but I was asked to create scripts that will be placed on a switch and automatically configure the port depending on the type of equipment connected. I did my research and understood the idea, but I can't figure out where to write the script or how to use a switch macro virtually without having a real. Please Help me!

Comment: What is the switch model?

Comment: it's Catalyst 3560-X series .if u have any advise or any information tell me :D

Comment: What do you mean about having a real? I don't understand that.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

macros is something like ***port profile***, you can attach what ever port to this port profile (macro) you already created . this port profile could be auto, meaning that once the switch recognize the connected device (CDP/LLDP) it will assign the configuration automatically to this port, (i.e. once the switch detect cisco ip phone it will assign the port voice vlan X and so on) [make use of this example](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-3750-series-switches/116515-configure-autosmartports-00.html) . other type is  Static Smart ports Configuration which is  used in  switch GUI configuration,where you configure the macros then assign the ports the macros manually. please make use of [this link](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3750/software/release/12-2_52_se/configuration/guide/3750scg/swmacro.html)

Comment: @WalidSlaaouiter Please accept this answer if it's what you are looking for. This will help others who have the same problem. :-)

Comment: Yes it was helpfull ty u both

Comment: @WalidSlaaouiter you should click the accept box on the left under voting to accept the answer. :-)